# Conflict between titlesec package and scrbook class after most recent update of TeXLive2019

Tags: koma-script, titlesec, scrbook

I just performed a full TL update (`--all`) (1 hr ago) and noticed that one of my documents which used to compile OK now gives an error.

After trial and error, found the problem shows up when including `titlesec` with `scrbook`. But this used to work just fine before the update of the TeX distribution.

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}%
%\documentclass[11pt]{book}%
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}

\errorcontextlines=200

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction, Summary of results and lookup table}
\section{Introduction}

stuff

\end{document}
```

Now `lualatex index.tex` gives

```
>lualatex index.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./index.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.134 seconds
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2019/02/01 v3.26b KOMA-Script document class (book)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty))

Class scrbook Warning: Usage of package `titlesec' together
(scrbook)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
(scrbook)              I'd suggest to use the package only
(scrbook)              if you really need it, because it breaks several
(scrbook)              KOMA-Script features, i.e., option `headings' and
(scrbook)              the extended optional argument of the section
(scrbook)              commands.
(scrbook)              Nevertheless, using requested
(scrbook)              package `titlesec' on input line 5.

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty

Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command \section
(titlesec)                detected. Using default spacing and no format.


Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command \subsection
(titlesec)                detected. Using default spacing and no format.


Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command \subsubsection
(titlesec)                detected. Using default spacing and no format.


Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command \paragraph
(titlesec)                detected. Using default spacing and no format.


Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command \subparagraph
(titlesec)                detected. Using default spacing and no format.

) (./index.aux)
chapter 1.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
}
\ttl@select ...@passexplicit \ttl@case \ttl@c {#2}
                                                  {#3}{#4}\fi \endgroup
\ttl@straight@ii ...t \ttl@select {#6}{#1}{#2}{#7}
                                                  \ttl@finmarks \@ifundefine...

l.13 \section{Introduction}

?
```

If I use the `book` class, the preceding MWE compiles with no errors.

What changed to make this fail?  Can one no longer use `titlesec` with `scrbook`?

TL 2019 on Ubuntu (under windows 10 linux subsystem)

Comment: `titlesec` and KOMA Script don't really go together. This is what the long warning message tries to tell you. The KOMA Script author has added some compatibility code to his document class to let `titlesec` do some of its work even with `scrbook`, but the compatibility code is only executed for `titlesec` versions before `2016/03/22`. If a newer version is detected, the workaround is inactive. You could contact the KOMA Script developer at https://komascript.de/forum or via email and ask for the fix to be reinstated for newer `titlesec` versions. ...

Comment: ... Of course (nowadays) it would be preferable not to load `titlesec` with KOMA Script classes at all. Instead one should try to mirror the effects with KOMA-Script built-ins. (I appreciate that this might take some work. But it would be more future proof.)

Comment: @moewe Markus already knows the issue, see https://komascript.de/release3.26b (German).

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the title and body of your posting to remove the somewhat confusing (and even misleading) references to LuaLaTeX. Feel free to revert.

Comment: You should have not used `titlesec` with `scrbook` for many years.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`titlesec` does not support KOMA-Script classes. So do not combine them. To change the layout of the chapter, section etc. titles you can use KOMA-Script options and `\RedeclareSectionCommand` & Co and you can redefine `\partlineswithprefixformat`, `\chapterlineswithprefixformat`, `\chapterlinesformat`, `\sectionlinesformat` and `\sectioncatchphraseformat`.

**Until version 3.26b KOMA-Script** has provided a dirty internal hack to make `titlesec` work with these classes, when the bundle was released. But it has checked the version of `titlesec` and has disabled the workaround if it was newer. See also https://komascript.de/release3.26b - »Bekannte Probleme« - »scrartcl, scrbook, scrreprt:« (German).

**Since KOMA-Script version 3.27** the internal `titlesec` workaround is removed and there will be no such internal workaround in KOMA-Script version 3.27 or later versions. But 3.27 provides a new hack with the package `scrhack` that can be enabled using the package option `standardsections` (not set by default). Then the commands for the sectioning levels are compatible with the standard classes but several KOMA-Script features regarding the sectioning commands are disabled (resulting in warnings).

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
  %11pt% default
]{scrbook}[2019/07/29]% needs prerelease of version 3.27 or newer
\usepackage[standardsections]{scrhack}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction, Summary of results and lookup table}
\KOMAScriptVersion
\section{Introduction}
stuff
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Hack with KOMA-Script version 3.26b or 3.27 (**not recommended**):
If you really want to use `titlesec` in combination with `scrbook`, then use `\RedeclareSectionCommands` for all section levels lower than `chapter` used in the document but not redefined by `\titleformat`:

```latex
\documentclass[
  %11pt% default
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\RedeclareSectionCommands{section}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction, Summary of results and lookup table}
\KOMAScriptVersion
\section{Introduction}
stuff
\end{document}
```

[image]