# Latex KOMA and titlesec incompatible again

Tags: errors, koma-script, titlesec

I've used KOMA and Titlesec for a while in the same document. I know there have been a lot of problems with those two packages in the past.

Nevertheless, I was using both together until this morning, when I updated my MikTex Installation. Seems like the Update of one of those packages threw off the nice balance between them. 
When compiling the error looks like this (no PDF created):
[image: Error Screenshot]
For the search engine here two lines of the logfile above:

- Missing number, treated as zero
- Illegal unit of measure

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I should deal with this issue? I am fairly new to Latex and don't understand it deep enough to really get into troubleshooting. 
I don't think I can work without one of these packages either. The removal results in a lot of errors as well.

Regards,
Simon

Edit: 
My titlesec settings:

```
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2ex}{1ex}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{1ex}{0ex}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0.5ex}{0ex}
```

Can anyone help me getting the same settings with koma?

Regards,

Simon

Comment: The correct way to deal with it, is not to use titlesec with a KOMA class. The KOMA-classes offer sensible commands to change the sectioning, use them instead. If you want to stick with titlesec use another class.

Comment: See [Conflict between titlesec package and scrbook class after most recent update of TeXLive2019](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511057/43317).

Comment: Show your `titlesec` settings. Maybe somebody can help to reproduce the desired result using KOMA-Script commands.

Comment: Hello esdd, I have updated my post. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @SimonJäggi The original question is answered and accepted. It would be nice, if you can ask a new question with a MWE or at least the code snippet above and the document class (`scrartcl` or `scrreprt` or `scrbook`). Then I can answer.

Comment: @esdd I created a new Question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515078/latex-koma-instead-of-titlesec-for-section-spacing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the announcement for the new release 3.27 at https://komascript.de/release3.27 you can find

> Der ziemlich üble Hack, der auf Kosten diverser Möglichkeiten von
>   KOMA-Script und unter Nutzung diverser interner Makros von titlesec
>   die Verwendung von titlesec mit KOMA-Script-Klassen eingeschränkt
>   ermöglicht hat, wurde entfernt.

Translated

> The pretty bad hack, which has allowed the use of titlesec with
>   KOMA-Script classes at the expense of various possibilities of
>   KOMA-Script and using various internal macros of titlesec, has been
>   removed.

This means that from now on, titlesec can no longer be used with the KOMA classes unless titlesec adds a support for this classes.

Comment: [... unless titlesec adds a support for these classes:] As the author of `titlesec`, I regret to say this won't happen in the foreseeable future. It's currently released under a very permissive license (MIT) and hosted on GitHub, so that anyone can fork it. Feel free to do it.