# Latex Koma instead of titlesec for section spacing

Tags: spacing, sectioning, koma-script, titlesec

As suggested by esdd I post this as a new question. Original post: [Latex KOMA and titlesec incompatible again](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515063/latex-koma-and-titlesec-incompatible-again?noredirect=1#comment1302350_515063).

I have some section spacing settings in titlesec, which I would like to "convert" to koma script. 
I use scrbook as document class. My options are as follows:

```
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2ex}{1ex}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{1ex}{0ex}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0.5ex}{0ex}
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Regards,

Simon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to change the settings for a single section level or `\RedeclareSectionCommands` to change the settings for a list of section levels.

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=2ex,% skip before section heading
  afterskip=1ex,% skip after section heading
  afterindent=true% indent the paragraph following the section heading
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  afterindent=true,
  afterskip=0ex,
  runin=false% freestanding heading
]{subsection,subsubsection}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=1ex]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=.5ex]{subsubsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=1ex]{paragraph}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `\DeclareSectionCommand`, see page 474 in the manual:

```
\DeclareSectionCommand[%
beforeskip=3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,
afterskip=-1em,
]{section}
```