# scrbook redefining sections without titlesec package

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, package-writing, scrbook

I am editing a package (which I did not write myself) where the `titlesec` package was used in combination with the `scrbook` document class. This produces an error, as explained in this post: [Conflict between titlesec package and scrbook class after most recent update of TeXLive2019](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511049/conflict-between-titlesec-package-and-scrbook-class-after-most-recent-update-of). I wish to fix this error, and get rid of the error message. I realize one must use the commands in the KOMA-class, but I don't know exactly how. Here is a minimal exaple:

Package:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage} 
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont}{\thesection}{0pt}{\phantomsection\fontsize{18pt}{20pt} \sffamily\center\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont}{\thesubsection}{0pt}{\fontsize{14pt}{16pt} \sffamily\center\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont}{\thesubsubsection}{0pt}{\scshape{\textbf{\normalsize #1}}}
% {left}{top}{below}{right}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt minus 0.5em}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{-2em plus 0.3em minus 0.3em}{-0.4em plus 0.2em minus 0.2em}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{-0.5em plus 0.2em}{-0.8em plus 0.5em minus 0em} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
```

The document:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=13pt,a4paper,openany,parskip=half,DIV=calc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{mypackage}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
    Some text.
\subsection{Subsection}
    More text.
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
    Text.
\end{document}
```

So the challenge is redefining the commands `section`, `subsection` and `subsubsection` as intended by the author of this class without using the `titlesec` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something like this:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
             {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
             {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
             {\center\phantomsection\fontsize{18pt}{20pt} \sffamily\MakeUppercase}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
             {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
             {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
             {\fontsize{14pt}{16pt} \sffamily\center\MakeUppercase}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
             {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
             {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
             {\scshape\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

which seems to have worked. Now I just need tips on how to (correctly) include the spacings from the `\titlespacing` commands.

Comment: I just tried using 0.7ex on the afterskip, which seemes to have produced something similar.

Comment: Using a KOMA-Script class do not redefine `\section` etc. using `\@startsection`. With an uptodate KOMA-Script version you will get warnings and several features of KOMA-Script will be deactivated.

Answer (score 2):

I see no way to apply `\MakeUppercase` to section titles with `komascript` methods. But it can be done.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[fontsize=13pt,a4paper,openany,parskip=half,DIV=calc]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for nonsense text

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  level=1,
  runin=false,
  font=\fontsize{18}{20}\sffamily\centering,
  beforeskip=10pt,
  afterskip=5pt,
]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  level=2,
  runin=false,
  font=\fontsize{14}{16}\sffamily\centering,
  beforeskip=6pt,
  afterskip=3pt,
]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  level=3,
  runin=false,
  font=\normalfont\normalsize\scshape,
  beforeskip=6pt,
  afterskip=3pt,
]{subsubsection}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\NewCommandCopy{\scrsection}{\section}
\NewCommandCopy{\scrsubsection}{\subsection}

\NewDocumentCommand{\uppercasesection}{msom}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
    #1*{\MakeUppercase{#4}}
  }{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}{%
      #1{\MakeUppercase{#4}}%
    }{%
      #1[#3]{\MakeUppercase{#4}}%
    }%
  }%
}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{}{\uppercasesection\scrsection}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{}{\uppercasesection\scrsubsection}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\section{Section}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\subsection{Subsection}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\end{document}
```

Adjust the spacing and font parameters to your taste.

[image]

Comment: This solution produced 14 errors, maybe because it is a package and the package does not provide `\RedeclareSectionCommand` ?

Comment: @Vebjorn My guess is that you have an older version of LaTeX. Try adding `\usepackage{xparse}`.

Comment: I don't think I use an older version. I use Overleaf

Comment: @Vebjorn I get no error.

Comment: Well, you have not made a package. Could also be other existing things in the package I was correcting that made it not work.

Comment: @Vebjorn Since a package is just `\input`, it can't make a difference. You've still to tell *what* errors you get.

Comment: It says `\RedeclareSectionCommand` is not defined.

Comment: @Vebjorn I guess you have an outdated version of the KoMa-script bundle, then.

Comment: @Vebjorn The example works for me on Overleaf, if I select TeXLive 2021 in the menu of the project on Overleaf.   If you load the package after `\documentclass{scrbook}` the command `\RedeclareSectionCommand` must be known, because it is provided by the class. `\RedeclareSectionCommand` was introduced in `scrbook` a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another suggestion redefining `\sectionlinesformat` to apply `\MakeUppercase`:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mypackage.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}
  {% no KOMA-Script class is used
    \RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\section}
      {\normalfont}{\thesection}{0pt}{\fontsize{18pt}{20pt} \sffamily\centering\MakeUppercase{#1}}
    \titleformat{\subsection}
      {\normalfont}{\thesubsection}{0pt}{\fontsize{14pt}{16pt} \sffamily\centering\MakeUppercase{#1}}
    \titleformat{\subsubsection}
      {\normalfont}{\thesubsubsection}{0pt}{\scshape{\normalsize #1}}
    %{indent}{before}{after}
    \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{10pt}{5pt}
    \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{6pt}{3pt}
    \titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{6pt}{3pt}
  }
  {% a KOMA-Script class is used
    \RedeclareSectionCommand[
      runin=false,
      font=\fontsize{18}{20}\mdseries,
      beforeskip=10pt,
      afterskip=5pt,
    ]{section}
    \RedeclareSectionCommand[
      runin=false,
      font=\fontsize{14}{16}\mdseries,
      beforeskip=6pt,
      afterskip=3pt,
    ]{subsection}
    \RedeclareSectionCommand[
      runin=false,
      font=\normalfont\normalsize\scshape,
      beforeskip=6pt,
      afterskip=3pt,
    ]{subsubsection}
    \renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
      \Ifstr{#1}{section}
        {\centering\MakeUppercase{#3#4}}
        {%
          \Ifstr{#1}{subsection}
            {\centering\MakeUppercase{#3#4}}
            {\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}}% original definition for other section levels
        }%
      }%
  }
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\end{filecontents}


\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[fontsize=13pt,a4paper,openany,parskip=half,DIV=calc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{mypackage}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for nonsense text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{document}
```

I have changed the spacings before and after the headings (like in the answer of @egreg), because the spacings in the question are curious.

[image]